# Youcompleteme for cpp and py

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

I have a project that has both c++ and python code in one folder. Is there any way I can configure you complete me (vim plugin) for both of them. Or would I just have to put them in separate folders?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, YCM supports more than one language in a folder. You can leave them in one folder. YCM supports many different languages.

Comment: What should be the config file for that?